# SVN and EMC Documentum

Tags: svn, documentum

Has anyone ever heard of Documentum being used to provide the backend store for Subversion?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't heard of this.

I don't think it is too likely, either. A subversion back-end needs to be a more general purpose datastore than it itself is and documentum is geared towards specialized storage and management of documents.

Someone could certainly shoehorn it, but at the risk of putting words in your mouth, it seems like you might be asking about something like a bridge where a documentum store could
be presented as a subversion repository.

Not knowing too much about documentum, I would say that this is unlikely, since svn is based
on the idea of directory based grouping of changesets and repository-wide versions.

A better match might be something like CVS, which is pretty much an aggregating interface
for an underlying revision management system (RCS).

Comment: While it might be possible to get it to work with a great deal of effort they aren't a great match.

Answer (score 1):

Some EMC man write unoffical article for integrate Composer with SVN:
http://paulcwarren.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/documentum-composer-and-eclipse-team/

Answer (score 0):

Though possible - doesn't make sense. Cause Documentum already provides some version management capabilities (similar to subversion). So it would be like having two version management systems stacked end to end.

I think whoever had this idea is confusing Documentum for a storage solution (like EMC Centera).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, all you can do is to integrate SVN with your composer to checkout-checkin code and other artifacts from the composer interface itself.
SVN cannot be used as Documentum content storage.